# Php mysqli query returns data but the result variable is null

Tags: php, mysqli

I have maybe a really simple problem for you but it's making me crazy.

In my index.php I call my `userHandler` to retrieve data from MySQL in this first line of code but whatever I do the $result stays null.

When debugging, I can clearly see that the MySQL returns one row and its not null.

```
$result = $userHandler->getUserByPhone($phoneNumber);

if ($result != NULL) {
}
```

Here is the method that returns result:

```
public function getUserByPhone($Phone) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user.* FROM user");
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->close();
    return $result;
}
```

And here is the screenshot of function 
[image]

and it returns null 
[image]

Edit: 
Ok i tought that after closing the statement the data would be lost. and thats true if i still want to return the data of the statement. but before closing i stored the data in a variable. and then close it. I checked in debug after closing the variable still has the data. 
[image]

Then i thought maybe the variable will be set null too (after all im a noob in php i can think none sense :D )
so i only returned True. But its still null in receiving end.

Comment: What are you trying to return?  You'll likely want to get the data out of $result before you close the statement.

Comment: If `$result` is not null inside the function, there's no way ot could be null outside. There must be something else going on that you're not showing.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php this closes the handle and any unread items. So this result could be null, as they have not been read. Just try commenting out $stmt->close();

Comment: @ShaunForsyth but its not an issue in other functions. and i see clearly in debug even after closing the statement the result that i stored in variable $result is not empty. 
I even checked with a return True; instead of return $result. its still Null.

Comment: Your debugger shows you're on the stmt_close() line, usually you need to be on the next line to show the result of that call.

Comment: @ShaunForsyth My mistake I removed my  $stmt->close(); and it returns now. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to pull the data you need out of `$result` prior to closing the statement.  Closing the statement will clear the statement and the related result set, rendering the value `null`.

Since getUserByPhone should seemingly return a user, I'd suggest that you get the user data out of the result and return that rather than closing the statement then trying to return the mysqli result object.

Something like:

```
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
$stmt->close(); 
return $user;
```

Comment: No I checked again. I still get null with thiw code